# How to achieve cardview like showing in this image (Image link in Body)

Tags: android, android-cardview

[I want to create cardview layout like this (Click here for Image)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a2J_ta2ku6aRlEoFsCL0DxrWG60q04Rx/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried looking here? https://android-arsenal.com/tag/154

Comment: Can you check this https://github.com/FarshidRoohi/cardViewPager

Comment: what exactly is a problem for you to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a CardView and use `card_view:cardCornerRadius=""` for the rounded corners and `card_view:cardElevation=""` for the shadow effect in your XML layout.

For the gradient background you need to create a new XML layout and do something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
            android:endColor="#FF00FF00"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

And set it as your background of your CardView

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add cardCornerRadius to your card view.

Below code you can check

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:padding="8dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I think this will help you